# urlopen is not working for python3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to fetch data from a url. I have tried the following in Python 2.7:

```
import urllib2 as ul
response = ul.urlopen("http://in.bookmyshow.com/")
page_content = response.read()
print page_content
```

This is working fine. But when i try it in Python 3.4 it is throwing an error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
```

I am using:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://in.bookmyshow.com/')
data = response.read()
print data
```

Comment: Please include the *full* error message, not just two lines of it. Also, your Python 3 code does not have correct syntax, so that code shouldn’t run at all.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (Python 3.4.3). You need to use `print(data)` in Python 3.

As a side note you may also want to consider [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which makes it way easier to interact via HTTP(S).

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://in.bookmyshow.com/')
>>> r.ok
True
>>> plaintext = r.text
```

Finally, if you want to get data from such complicated pages (which are intended to be displayed, as opposed to an API), you should have a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) which will make your life easier as well.